# Find array position greater than a threshold where the next position is less than the threshold (numpy)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there an efficient way to return array positions where the value in a given position is greater than a threshold value AND the subsequent position is less than that threshold? I am able to accomplish this in a loop, but it is very slow for arrays with 100,000+ entries.

As an example,

```
x=[4,9,1,5,7,8,10,11,2,4]

threshold=3

# find elements greater than 3 and where the next element is less than 3

return [1,7] #corresponding to indexes for values 9 and 11 in x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `x[:-1] > threshold`: check the current value
- `x[1:] < threshold`: check the next value
- `np.flatnonzero`: get the true indices

---

```
x = np.array([4,9,1,5,7,8,10,11,2,4])
​
np.flatnonzero((x[:-1] > threshold) & (x[1:] < threshold))
# array([1, 7])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution

```
In [148]: x
Out[148]: array([ 4,  9,  1,  5,  7,  8, 10, 11,  2,  4])

# masks for satisfying your condition
In [149]: gt = x>3
In [150]: lt = x[1:]<3

# multiply the boolean masks and find the indices of `True` values
In [151]: np.where(gt[:-1] * lt)
Out[151]: (array([1, 7]),)

# return indices as an array
In [152]: np.where(gt[:-1] * lt)[0]
Out[152]: array([1, 7])
```